# iOS: NSBundle URLForResource fails after renaming project

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, nsbundle

I've just renamed my Xcode 4 project by slowly double clicking on the project blue banner in the project navigator and modifying the value then pressing Enter.

The renaming was successful and the project compiles, deploys and runs successfully.

There is one minor problem. I would like to modify the string value in the following line to reflect the project name change:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyProjectName" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

When I change the `@"MyProjectName"` to read `@"MyNewProjectName"` the app crashes since the retrieved value from this is nil.

Where is the value you specify being looked up? I've renamed the `MyProjectName.xcdatamodeld` to be `MyNewProjectName.xcdatamodeld` but that hasn't helped. It's bugging me that I can't update this string.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from the device and / or deleting the app from the simulator.  Recompile and run it.